# How to keep local roles separated from the ones loaded from ansible-galaxy?

Tags: ansible

I observed that roles downloaded from galaxy get installed inside the `roles/` directory, where we already have our in-house ones, making quite hard to distiguish between external ones and internal ones.

Is there a way to keep them in separated directories, so we can avoid confusions?

In most cases I would expect to have a script that is updating the galaxy ones and that we would not modify them internally.

Comment: Not only to avoid confusions, keeping external roles in a separated folder is useful to include that folder in the .gitignore :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is no standard way of doing this but you can use Ansibles behavior to your advantage.

Ansible searches in two locations for roles:

- In the `roles` directory relative to your playbook
- The path you configured in your `ansible.cfg`

What you now need to do depends on where you actually store you roles. We are storing our roles relative to our playbooks, so everything is in the same git repo.

Now you could [define in your `ansible.cfg`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#roles-path) to look for roles in an additional folder:

```
roles_path=./galaxy_roles
```

`ansible-galaxy` will install roles by default into the first found path of `roles_path`, so make sure to add the galaxy folder as very first if you have multiple role paths. You do not need to add the `roles` folder explicitly. Ansible will by default always search for roles inside the `./roles` folder relative to the playbook.

Alternatively you can also instruct galaxy to install to a different location:

```
ansible-galaxy install --roles-path=./galaxy_roles foo
```

Comment: Thanks, this works the trick is that you need to put the roles-galaxy as the first path in the list in order not to have to specify `--roles-path` on galaxy install. If you use simple role names (not dot) internally there is no risk of having them replaced by galaxy ones, which always have a dot in them.

Comment: Would this work for locally created roles i.e. I ran ansible-galaxy init myrole under /my_workspace. I'd like to make changes, test them and then deploy or install them on the machine so I can use my role with any playbook located anywhere i.e. ansible-galaxy install /path/to/my_workspace/my_role tries to download the role and fails, I want it to install the role from the local directory, can you please help me ?

Comment: If you have your roles all stored in a specific global location, you could just set the `roles_path` to point to that directory. No need to "install" it. Or create a symlink in `roles/` pointing to the role.

Comment: Is there any difference between `roles_path=./galaxy_roles` and `roles_path= galaxy_roles`?

Comment: Most probably not.

Answer (score 5):

The @udonhan inheritance answer could be not enough if you have internal/custom roles that are not always relative to a playbook, I mean global roles.

You can manage multiple roles path in ansible.cfg file, so you can define an ansible.cfg file in your project path with:

```
[defaults]
roles_path    = ./roles:./roles_internal
```

The "./roles" path can be used for ansible-galaxy roles, and the "./roles_internal" can be used for your internal/custom roles

Now when you execute

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requeriments.yml
```

Galaxy roles are installed in "./roles" by default

NOTE: You must be sure that ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH env variable is not set or it will override the ansible.cfg settings. For testing:

```
unset ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `roles_path = ./roles` and `roles_path = roles`?