# using ansible modules from git repository?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook and a bunch of modules I wrote.

Now I want to reuse the same modules in my next playbook for a different project.

I really want to push those modules to a public git repository and then somehow tell ansible to use the modules from the git repository.

(kinda like npm package.json referencing github)

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do that.

For now, I am using a workaround where I tell people to npm install the repository, and then define ANSIBLE_LIBRARY variable.

How can I tell the playbook to load modules from a github repository or some other remote location?

Comment: That's a very good question and I think it is a terrible limitation of Ansible Galaxy to only allow sharing of roles and not provide a way to share modules.

Comment: In the meantime I figured our modules can be nested inside roles and since Ansible 2 this even works with plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually modules can be nested inside roles since quite a long time. Since Ansible 2 this even is possible with most of the plugins.

The folders where the [modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_modules.html#getting-your-module-into-ansible) & [plugins](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#distributing-plugins) need to be stored inside the role is the same as on playbook level. Modules go into `library`, plugins go into `*_plugins` (`action_plugins`, `callback_plugins`, `filter_plugins` etc)

To make the module/plugin then available the role has to be applied to the playbook (or added as a dependency of another role)

Only exception known to me are variable plugins and that perfectly makes sense. Since variable plugins are executed when the inventory is read, which happens before roles are interpreted.

`vars_plugins` still can be distributed in roles, but the [path needs to be added in the `ansible.cfg`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#vars-plugins). Fortunately you can also use wildcards in paths:

```
vars_plugins = roles/*/vars_plugins
```

And no, all of this is not documented in any way. :)

Finally, to distribute roles you can use [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/):

```
ansible-galaxy install foo
```

Nothing wrong with directly using git. Ansible Galaxy actually only is a tool to install git repositories. But since Galaxy is the Ansible standard I suggest to at least provide a Galaxy compatible format. A good (best?) practice how to install Galaxy roles separate from the projects roles can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34902605/2753241).

Here's an example for an action plugin: https://galaxy.ansible.com/udondan/ssh-reconnect/

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for that at the moment. Maybe you can add a playbook to download the modules to your project to avoid npm, but thats even not that nice.

I have my custom modules in a directory next to my playbooks. This directory is defined in my global ansible.cfg file:

```
library = /usr/share/ansible
```

The only drawbag here is that i allways have the same version for modules on all playbboks.

Comment: Actually it is possible. It's just not documented. See my answer. below/above. :)